# Javascript Run one click then another

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

What I'm trying to do is make it open the breed_selector dropdown menu, and then select breed1, then .click, then move onto the next breed and click, and continue, It needs to do this three times, but unfortunately it only selects the first breed of dog and clicks, not all three.

Thanks

```
    (function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector).options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="Labrador"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
   }
}

        var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="poodle"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();



})();
```

At the moment, it just doesn't do anything,

I have tried

```
var  = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i].text=="poodle", "Labrador", "pug"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
```

But the above doesn't work either, any input would be great, Thanks :)

UPDATED CODE which still doesn't work

```
(function() {

    var x = document.getElementById("breed_selector").options;
   for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        var text = x[i].text;
        if(x[i].text === "Labrador" && text === "Pug"){
            x[i].selected=true;
document.getElementsByClassName("shop")[0].click();
            break;
   }
}


})();
```

Comment: Why are you bothering with triggering the `click` event of the element and just don't invoke the code that the `click` event is bound to?

Comment: Hey, I honestly don't have the slightest clue what you are on about, I only recently got into JS. It's only finding the breed for the first one and not all of them and clicking ?

Comment: In your updated code, why are you comparing same variable with two different values and that too with **&&** condition? It will always give `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to click on ALL the options of the `select` element:

```
var breedSelector = document.getElementById("breed_selector");
var howMany = breedSelector.length;
var buttonShop = document.querySelector(".shop");

for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
    breedSelector.selectedIndex = i;
    buttonShop.click();
}
```

Note, though, that it will click the button several times in quick succession.

In order to select only certain options based on their value, you could try something like:

```
var breedSelector = document.getElementById("breed_selector");
var whichOnes = ["Labrador", "Poodle", "Golden"]; //whichever you want.
var buttonShop = document.querySelector(".shop");

whichOnes.forEach(function(breed){
    breedSelector.selectedIndex = [].findIndex.call(breedSelector, function(option) { return option.textContent == breed});
    buttonShop.click();
}
```